# Rails completed 200 OK but $.ajax() calling 'error' callback instead of 'success'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

My controller handles the ajax request like follows (simplified):

```
def create
 ...
 @answer = Answer.new(video: video_file)
 if @answer.save
  render json: @answer.video.url
 else
  ...
 end
end
```

This is how my ajax function is defined:

```
$.ajax({
        url :  "/answers",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Success!")
        },    
        error: function(data) {
          console.log("Error!",data)
        }
      });
```

This is the response from Rails server:

`Completed 200 OK in 13954ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)`

And this is what `data` returned by the server looks like (using Chrome console):

```
{readyState: 4, responseText: "http://some_url.com", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

However, the 'error' callback is executed and not the 'success' one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use your browser's debugging tools to inspect the output of your server.

Comment: Sorry, I did. I edited the question and added the detail.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the returned JSON if key is not specified is interpreted as malformed.

Parsing json as follows solves the problem:

```
render json: {answer_video: @answer.video.url}
```